# I don't know why this while loop doesn't stop iterating

Tags: python, python-3.x

It's a challenge on codewars.com, but I can't figure out why this while loop doesn't work

```py
def digital_root(n):
    # Creating variable combine to have the sum
    combine = 0
    # as long as n is more than two numbers.
    while n > 10:
        # converting n to string to iterate
        for i in str(n):
            # getting the sum each element in n
            combine += int(i)
        # reset n to be equal to the combined result
        n = combine
    return combine
```

also, any solutions will be appreciated, here is the link to the challenge 
https://www.codewars.com/kata/sum-of-digits-slash-digital-root

Comment: please tell us some context here. What is n? What are you trying to achieve with this function?

Comment: n is a number, here is the link to what I want to achieve https://www.codewars.com/kata/sum-of-digits-slash-digital-root

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do something like the following:

```
def digital_root(n):
    combined = 0
    while True:
        for i in str(n):
            combined += int(i)

        print combined

        # this is the condition to check if you should stop
        if len(str(combined)) < 2:
            return combined
        else:
            n = combined
            combined = 0
```

EDIT: you could also do it without converting to a `str` like you did:

```
def digital_root(n):
    combined = 0
    while True:
        for i in str(n):
            combined += int(i)
        print combined
        if combined < 10:
            return combined
        else:
            n = combined
            combined = 0
```

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate your help :)

Answer (score 1):

interesting;)

```
def digital_root(n):
    return n if n < 10 else digital_root(sum(int(i) for i in str(n)))
```

Comment: Great, I love it ^^

Answer (score 0):

It is nice that you are updating `n`, but what about `combine`. Perhaps a a reset is needed at the end of every iteration?

Comment: I am really a #%$*@!
Thanks for the note

Comment: We've all been there, no worries! That's why coding is fun.